# Will Exo Mars serve as a relay for non ESA/Roscosmos missions?

Tags: deep-space-network, exomars

I know that Exo Mars TGO is intended to be a relay for Exo Mars Schiaparelli and Exo Mars Rover.

However the orbiter could also serve as a relay for other missions.

Is there currently any plan for doing so ?

Comment: Mars express did serve to help monitoring Curiosity and Phoenix. It's only fair to assume exo mars could too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Electra radio package is provided by NASA/JPL, and NASA fully expects to [utilize it's capabilities](http://marsmobile.jpl.nasa.gov/news/whatsnew/index.cfm?FuseAction=ShowNews&NewsID=1664) for it's own future missions.

> Plans call for the TGO to use its Electra radios for communication
>   with ESA's 2018 ExoMars Rover and Russia's Lander as well as with
>   NASA's 2016 Mars lander and 2020 Mars rover.

2016 Mars lander is the Phoenix-derived InSight ( now delayed to 2018 ), and of course 2020 MSL/Curiosity heritage rover.

Maybe it's important to mention that not all Mars orbiters have equal contribution opportunities as relays, due to their chosen science orbits. So [TGO will add valuable](http://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/europes-new-mars-mission-bringing-nasa-radios-along) capacity thanks to it's favorable orbit.

> TGO's Electra radios use a design from JPL with special features for
>   relaying data from a rover or stationary lander to an orbiter passing
>   overhead. Relay of information from Mars-surface craft to Mars
>   orbiters, then from Mars orbit to Earth, enables receiving much more
>   data from the surface missions than would otherwise be possible.
>
> As an example of Electra capabilities, during a relay session between
>   an Electra on the surface and one on an orbiter, the radios can
>   maximize data volume by actively adjusting the data rate to be slower
>   when the orbiter is near the horizon from the surface robot's
>   perspective, faster when it is overhead.
>
> NASA's Curiosity Mars rover and Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter (MRO)
>   already use Electra technology for relay of data. NASA's Mars
>   Atmosphere and Volatile Evolution (MAVEN) spacecraft, in orbit since
>   2014, also carries an Electra radio.
>
> Due to improvements in the newest Electra radios and reduced
>   interference levels compared with MRO, TGO's relay radios are expected
>   to have a relay signal about twice as strong as MRO's. Compared to
>   MAVEN's highly elongated orbit, TGO has a planned orbit similar to
>   MRO's relay-favorable orbit at about 250 miles (400 kilometers) in
>   altitude and nearly circular in shape.